# Not able to get the cell details in WPF DataGrid cell

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have datagrid with item source bound with data from database.It has two  data template with bounded value using value converter.( I have converted  employee ID(frow1 column)  to image path using converter).Now I want to show the employee ID when ever the user double click on the cell with image .when I have run the application data grid populated with employee images successfully.

So far I have tried as below using the DataGridCellInfo as shown in the below code.I have set CurrentCell="{Binding CellInfo, Mode=TwoWay}"  in data grid xamal.Here CellInfo is public property

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dtGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"   
 Margin="0,0,0,0"  SelectionUnit="Cell" 
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"           
SelectionMode="Single"  
CurrentCell="{Binding CellInfo, Mode=OneWayToSource}"   
 VerticalAlignment="Top" RowHeight="50" ColumnWidth="50"  
AlternatingRowBackground="{x:Null}"  AlternationCount="2" 
CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
CanUserSortColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="None" 
GridLinesVisibility="None" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{x:Null}" 
 VerticalGridLinesBrush="{x:Null}" >
   <DataGrid.Columns>
                  <DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="SizeToCells"  IsReadOnly="True" >     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                     <DataTemplate>
          <Button  Background="#FF1D5BBA"                                   
              PreviewMouseDoubleClick="Button_PreviewMouseDoubleClick"  >
                  <Image    Source="{Binding Path=frow1, 
                   Converter=StaticResource 
                  prfileconverter},  
                   Mode=Default}" />
         </Button>
                      </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My code behind:

```
private void Button_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    { 
       MessageBox.Show(CellInfo.ToString())
    }


private DataGridCellInfo _cellInfo;
public DataGridCellInfo CellInfo
    {
        get {


               return _cellInfo;
           }
        set
           {
            _cellInfo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CellInfo");
                     //this is to refresh through  INotifyPropertyChanged    
         }
    }
```

Here I am stuck with how to show the employee id when I do MouseDoubleClick on the cell.when I double click on the cell I am getting Message  Box saying"System.Windows.Control.DataGridCellInfo".I am not getting cell item(Employee ID)

Comment: Try `CellInfo.Item.ToString()`

Comment: Showing error: null refernce excecption was un handled

Comment: What's your DataContext / ViewModel here?

Comment: Keep in mind that DataGridCellInfo represents the _row_ (and the object bound to that row), not the _cell_ per se.

Comment: DataContext is given in the constructor :transportListDataView = loademp().DefaultView;  dtGrid.ItemsSource = transportListDataView;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `DataGridTemplateColumn` doesn't have access to the `CellInfo.Item` (it doesn't exist)

The easiest way to do this is through your `Button_PreviewMouseDoubleClick` event, by binding the Tag property of the Button to your data, then accessing it in the event handler like this:

```
<Button PreviewMouseDoubleClick="Button_PreviewMouseDoubleClick" Tag="{Binding Path=frow1}">....
```

Then in your event handler do this:

```
private void Button_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   var button = (Button)sender; 
   MessageBox.Show(button.Tag.ToString());
}
```